# Squid Forward Proxy on Cloudflare

Tags: squid, cloudflare

Is it possible to set up a forward proxy using Squid and still have Cloudflare CDN working?
For example, I currently have Squid running on Ubuntu, with this being the squid.conf file.

acl myhost srcdomain [my domain] http_access allow myhost

http_port 8080

acl client src [home ip address] # Home IP http_access allow client

acl permittedips src [cloudflare ip] acl permittedips src [another cloud flare ip etc...]

This works fine with a DNS record that bypasses Cloudflare's CDN, but if I change acl myhost srcdomain [a cloud flare domain] to something that passes through Cloudflare's CDN, I get Cloudflare DNS Resolution Errors (1001).

Comment: Those are somewhat orthogonal concepts... what exactly are you trying to achieve?  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, there is no reason why not.  It depends on what it is you want to do, though.

For example, don't expose your squid proxy to the end users querying your site, and don't put caching proxies in front of the CDN.

Aside from that, the CDN doesn't much care what your application servers are doing, as long as they give out your content.  You can run whatever HTTP daemon you like.  Did you try it?